# Stuck in Python Directory

Tags: python

I need to select a folder that contains few images and after that, I need to select each image one by one and copy it to the new folder every time.

For example a folder `Images` contain 5 images named 1,2,3,4,5 and I need to select image 1st and make a new folder by any name and paste that image into it, after that, select 2nd image and copy it to the second new folder, then 3rd image into 3rd new folder and so on till the end.

Comment: There is no question here. Please see [ask] and provide whatever code you tried to start working on the problem

Comment: show your code and full error message.

Answer (score 2):

```
from shutil import copyfile
import glob
path = '/home/Desktop/Yash/*' #path of your images * is for glob
new_path = '/home/Desktop/Yash/extra/' # new path for image folder
for i in glob.glob(path):        
    try:
        path1 = new_path+i.split('.')[0].split('/')[-1] # to get folder name
        os.mkdir(path1)
        copyfile(i,path1+'/'+i.split('/')[-1]) # to get file name. i = src and other path is destination
    except:
        pass
```